# Why does the WPF designer fail to load libraries that call into unmanaged DLLs?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 SP1, and have a test application with the following modules:

1. a C++ DLL
2. a C++/CLI DLL that uses #1
3. a C# WPF application that uses #2

When I try to use classes from #2 as resources in the WPF XAML, the designer won't let me:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:lib1="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary1;assembly=ClassLibrary1" <- ERROR
```

The error is: "Assembly 'ClassLibrary1' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built."

But when I use a class from the C++/CLI DLL in the code-behind of the application main window, everything works fine. Class1 is created, and in its constructor it calls into the C++ DLL, no problem.

```
using ClassLibrary1;

...

public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //use in code-behind
        Class1 tmp = new Class1();
        tmp.FirstName = "foo";
        Title = tmp.FirstName;
    }
}
```

If I modify the C++/CLI assembly, remove its call into the C++ DLL and rebuild everything, the designer stops complaining and loads the C++/CLI assembly without complaint.

I suspect this problem has something to do with where the WPF designer looks for dynamic libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure of a workaround, but I believe VS/WPF Designer copies the assemblies to a temporary location and loads them from there. So it's probably not copying your C++ DLL.

Comment: I think you are very close to right, but not quite. The assemblies (even the unmanaged ones) are actually copied, but like Rick says below, the WPF designer can't find them unless they're somewhere on the system path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the Visual Studio designer copies your assemblies to a temporary location, but doesn't copy your unmanaged dependencies, you can run into this problem.

The simplest solution, although not ideal, is to add a folder that contains your unmanaged dependencies to the `PATH` environment variable, and then start `DevEnv.exe` with that `PATH`.

You can do this either by:

- Adding the folder to the System environment variables using Computer -> Properties
- Using a batch file that sets the path and then starts DevEnv

The problem with this solution is that as the unmanaged dependencies are rebuilt Visual Studio tends to "hang onto" them or not use the new ones and so you end up needing to exit and restart Visual Studio after using the designer to properly totally rebuild everything and this can be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Yep, this must be it: the designer only finds my DLLs if they're on the system path. If I copy my library to the system32 folder as suggested here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/a4cd0d5f-71dc-4b2c-977d-0a6825838160), instead of into the output folder, the designer finds it. So I'm sure your solution will work. I am really not looking forward to dealing with the out-of-date-DLL problem you're describing, though. Bleh.

Comment: @Matthew: For design purposes you may not care at all if the unmanaged DLL is up to date.  It could be a week old.  Experiment to find what works best.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real solution, but sometimes it helps: rebuild using "AnyCPU" (not "x64", because the designer is a 32bit process) and in "Release" mode, close and re-open Visual Studio. And, yes: this is very annoying...