# Why does my referenced file fail to load from my WPF user control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, reference

Basically, my project is following the setup from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036631/why-does-the-wpf-designer-fail-to-load-libraries-that-call-into-unmanaged-dlls), except my C# WPF project is using .NET 4.0, but I'm having a different problem. My view model can use the managed projects just fine, however, when I reference the managed projects from a user control, whether in the xaml code or the code behind, that control will not render on my view due to a "file not found" exception. (My WPF project builds successfully)

My best guess as to the cause of this is that my managed class is using .NET 3.5 and my wpf project is in .NET 4.0. But this doesn't make sense and I can't figure out how to get around this issue.

EDIT: I've found that the problem happens when I try to use my managed classes in my constructor. But this also happens whenever I use them in the loaded and initialized events of the user control. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The file not found exception should tell you what file is missing. I'm betting that your managed classes in the one DLL have a reference to some DLL that is not being referenced by the WPF project - which would mean its not copied into the output directory. To summarize: make sure all your referenced assemblies are available wherever the actual executable is.

Comment: The WPF project does not have an executable, it has a dll. However, putting the managed dll in with the output folder with the WPF project's dll does not remedy the problem. I actually found that the problem was trying to use something from the managed project in the user control's constructor.

Comment: That sounds a bit odd. You should be able to use whatever you want (as long as it is referenced and the DLL containing that code is available at runtime) inside a UserControl's constructor. That is, unless you're doing something dynamically (like loading it with MEF or similar).

Comment: Another related problem, I can't use my managed code in the loaded or initialized event for that user control or any other basic controls within my user control. Doing so causes the same initial problem.