# Why does a custom control raise an exception in the Designer, yet work at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I have a third-party display control for a USB camera's image, set up in its own window, using XAML as follows:

```xaml
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="ControlWrapperAppWPF.CameraView"
    Title="Camera Image" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TCUSB;assembly=TCC">
        <custom:TCC Name="tC" Loaded="tC_Loaded" />
</Window>
```

In the Design pane, a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is displayed (beneath a link to *Click here to reload the designer*). The error details include:

> Could not load file or assembly 'TCR, Version=2.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=32fe4fab5501c8fe' or one of its dependencies.

TCC.dll (referenced from my XAML) uses TCR.dll, and their respective dependencies are numerous. I have had to copy lots of DLLs to both `\bin\Debug` and `\bin\Release` folders. Should they be copied somewhere else too (or instead)?

TCR.dll itself is actually version 2.1.3.**1025**, so this may or may not be the problem, however, I receive no such complaints at runtime. The project builds with no warnings, and when I execute either a Debug or Release build, the third-party control window works OK.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I can only offer some advice: Start two copies of Visual Studio, and from instance `A` use `Debug | Attach To Process` to attach to instance `B`. Then in instance `B` open your project with the faulty third party control and open the designer that gives a problem - then see if instance `A` finds any exceptions. You might need to go to `Debug | Exceptions` and turn on "thrown" for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in instance `A` first.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. That is a neat trick, but I can't seem to catch the Designer error. I did try to `throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException()` when my App starts, but this was only caught in instance `B`. I have turned on "thrown" for the other exception types, just in case. Is there a better way to deliberately throw a CLR Exception in instance `B` to check that I've attached instance `A` correctly?

Comment: You could probably make an empty default user control and add it to a form in the project in instance `B` and then change its constructor to throw an exception, then open the form with it in.

Comment: (...cont) That is, open the form in the IDE's Design pane.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that technique will definitely come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6036800/1236073

The third party control I am using does seem to reference unmanaged DLLs, so everything now adds up!

I have flagged my question as a duplicate, although it offers some additional keywords not in the original post that may help a future searcher.