# Visual Studio fails to load native dll in design mode

Tags: c#, c, wpf, visual-studio, dll

I have a C# WPF application that loads a native C dll using DllImport. The DLL functions is mapped to a C# class.

The WPF designer tries to load the DLL because the window's ViewModel constructor call a native function, but can't find the DLL.

I've copied the DLL to the output directory and the application runs fine, can debug and step into the DLL, it is just the designer that complains, and sometimes hangs Visual Studio.

I've tried putting the Dll in my project directory and in the obj directory to no avail.

Where does Visual studio 2012 try to load a native dll from.

Comment: You can skip the function call by checking whether you're in design mode?

Comment: Thanks @SriramSakthivel, did a search and found how to do it. It works, but adds code just for the designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having this error with a Wrapper C++/CLI DLL that wraps some legacy C++ library code, and I found some information at the link below. I looked on my C: drive in my AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache and I see that VisualStudio is copying the Wrapper DLL into a series of Temporary folders, but not the native C++ DLLs.  I confirmed by running the "Everything" utility and see scads of copies of my DLL within folders contained in the ShadowCache folder, none of which have the native DLLs.

It's a shame to have to create special processes, scripts or batch files just to utilize the designer view for Visual Studio, but as far as I can tell there's no good way around it.

What I've done is to create a folder on my C: drive containing every native DLL I currently or might eventually wrap with a C++/CLI implementation and add that folder to my Environment PATH statement. After this update I've not thrown an exception.

[Why does the WPF designer fail to load libraries that call into unmanaged DLLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036631/why-does-the-wpf-designer-fail-to-load-libraries-that-call-into-unmanaged-dlls)

Answer (score 0):

You can always create an "Intialize()" method in your class and move the offending code from the constructor to the initializer. When you instantiate the class at runtime you call the Initialze() method of course, but in XAML the code doesn't run.

As someone else mentioned, you can check if you're in design-time which is, of course, inelegant.

Another approach I often use is to create "DesignerData" wrapper classes.

For instance:

```
public class MyDesignerData
{
   private static MyViewModel _vm;

   public MyViewModel ViewModel
   {
       get { return _vm; }
   }

   public MyDesignerData()
   {
       _vm = new MyViewModel();
       //do stuff to setup MyViewModels properties
       //with data that you want to see in the designer
   }
}
```

In your view, you can use this class like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.MyViews"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.MyViews"
             d:DataContext="{Binding AnalysisVm, Source={d:DesignInstance 
                  IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type={x:Type local:MyDesignerData}}}"
```

Of course, now with [XAML HotReload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2019) sometimes I just forget about mucking around with the designer is some circumstances. It can really turn into a time suck!